# Is batch size of 1 a valid choice for a very deep neural network with high memory requirement?

Tags: deep-learning, training, image-processing, image-segmentation, memory

I am training a very deep neural network (Panoptic-DeepLab) with a ResNet34 backbone on Google Colab on CityScapes dataset for Panoptic Segmentation, and noticed that, with a big crop size, the batch size has to be decreased to 1 image per batch, otherwise CUDA out of memory issues start to occur. While I know that this can create skewness in the training and it will likely be very hard to attain good convergence, can I ask this question in general to the experts: how valid is a batch size of 1 generally considered in image-based processing? The images in consideration can be considered large (high resolution). The optimizer used is Adam alongwith a warm up polynomial learning rate (with base around 0.00005), and 90k iterations.

(I understand that it would possibly be a good idea to try out a smaller crop size and bigger batch size, but would like to know the feedback from the community anyway)

Comment: You can do gradient accumulation to artificially use a higher batch size even if only one image can fit in the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research, I found that a batch size of 1 is quite common in deep-learning image processing use-cases where there are high memory/GPU requirements for model training. In fact, it gives better results at times.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).